# Aligning 3 elements together side by side

Tags: html, css

So I want to align these three elemts so they are side by side on the page, first the '1' follow by the image follow by the 'text'. I cannot work out at all how to do this can somebody help?

My HTML:

```
<div class="chart-game">
<div id="1">
    <h1>1</h1>
</div>
<div id="1img">
    <img src="http://images.pushsquare.com/games/ps3/call_of_duty_ghosts/cover_large.jpg">
</div>
<div id="1p">
    <p>Text</p>
</div>    
</div>
```

My CSS:

```
.chart-game img {
width:100px;
height:100px;
}
#1 {
display:inline-block;
margin-right:10px;
}
#1img {
display:inline-block;
margin-right:10px;
}
#1p {
display:inline-block;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/c7tLr/):

html:

```
<div class="chart-game">
        <div class="chart-game-inner">
            <h1>1</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="chart-game-inner">
            <img src="http://images.pushsquare.com/games/ps3/call_of_duty_ghosts/cover_large.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="chart-game-inner">
            <p>Text</p>
        </div>   
    </div>
```

css:

```
.chart-game img {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
}
.chart-game-inner {
    display : inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the names of the Id **to not** contains any numbers at the beginning of the string.
The code is working fine

**New HTML**

```
<div class="chart-game">
<div id="header">
    <h1>1</h1>
</div>
<div id="image">
</div>
<div id="text-header">
    <p>Text</p>
</div>    
</div>
```

**And the CSS**

```
.chart-game img {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
}
#header {
  display:inline-block;
  margin-right:10px;
}
#image {
    width: 50px;
    height:50px;

    background : #dedede;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-right:10px;
}
#text-header {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: I have done this, however you know the text in the <p> tag, when I write to much instead of starting a new line underneath the text written it moves the whole text line below the image and the heading. Is there any way to format it so it writes in a paragraph form?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [floats](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp)

**css**

```
.chart-game img {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    float:left;
}
#1 {
    display:inline-block;
    margin-right:10px;      
}
#1img {
    display:inline-block;
    margin-right:10px;
    float:left;
}
#1p {
    display:inline-block;
}
h1{
    float:left;
}
p{
    float:left;
}
```

Additional class identifiers are allowed to start with a number, but ID identifiers are not.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s79Mh/3/)